# Is overriding an ActiveRecord relation's count() method okay?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have the following relationship in my Rails app:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
end

class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I want parents to be able to see a list of their chatty kids, and use the count in paginating through that list. Here's a way to do that (I know it's a little odd, bear with me):

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids do
    def for_chatting
      proxy_association.owner.kids.where(:chatty => true)
    end
  end
end
```

But! Some parents have millions of kids, and `p.kids.for_chatting.count` takes too long to run, even with good database indexes. I'm pretty sure this cannot be directly fixed. But! I can set up a `Parent#chatty_kids_count` attribute and keep it correctly updated with database triggers. Then, I can:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids do
    def for_chatting
      parent = proxy_association.owner
      kid_assoc = parent.kids.where(:chatty => true)
      def kid_assoc.count
        parent.chatty_kids_count
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then `parent.kids.for_chatting.count` uses the cached count and my pagination is fast.

But! Overriding `count()` on singleton association objects makes the *uh-oh, I am being way too clever* part of my brain light up big-time.

I feel like there's a clearer way to approach this. Is there? Or is this a "yeah it's weird, leave a comment about why you're doing this and it'll be fine" kind of situation?

Comment: Seems a little weird to be doing pagination on millions of records, no? Is it really necessary to have the count?

Comment: Why not use ```parent.chatty_kids_count```? And think about scopes on kids model or kids association in parent model

Comment: @mp94: Yes, I'm aware doing pagination on millions of records is weird, and that "just don't use the count" would be a way to solve the problem. Let's pretend I do want to use the count, for Reasons.

Comment: @kolas: I'm using will_paginate, which automagically calls count() on the association. Yes, I know I could stop using it, or hack it. I'm well aware of scopes, but don't know how I'd patch count() in that case.

Comment: You can use wrapper for collection like here https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/pull/818#issuecomment-252788488, just override count method

Comment: @kolas Yeah, wrapping the collection in a delegator sounds does sound cleaner than rewriting a method on it. Thanks! If you write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit:

I checked the code of will_paginate, seems like it is not using `count` method of AR relation, but i found that you can provide option `total_entries` for paginate

```
@kids = @parent.kids.for_chatting.paginate(
  page:          params[:page], 
  total_entries: parent.chatty_kids_count
)
```

> ### This is not working
>
> You can use wrapper for collection like here
>   https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/pull/818#issuecomment-252788488​,
>   just override count method.
>
> ```
> class RelationWrapper < SimpleDelegator
>   def initialize(relation, total_count)
>     super(relation)
>     @total_count = total_count
>   end
>
>   def count
>     @total_count 
>   end
> end
>
> # in a controller:
> relation = RelationWrapper.new(@parent.kids.for_chatting, parent.chatty_kids_count)
> ```

Comment: Amusingly, this approach does not seem to work. When I override the singleton's count(), will_paginate seems to respect that; however, when I override it with the delegator, it does not. I... I don't know how this is possible. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Welp, that's what I get for accepting an answer before actually testing it.

Comment: @Nate new solution for you