# Why do a singleton method and a delegated method behave differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Okay, this is kind of a followup to this question: [Is overriding an ActiveRecord relation's count() method okay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922421/is-overriding-an-activerecord-relations-count-method-okay) Basically I have a relation I want to paginate on, and counting it is slow, so I'm overriding `count()` with a cached counter attribute.

I have:

```
class CountDelegator < SimpleDelegator
  def initialize(obj, total_count)
    super(obj)
    @total_count = total_count
  end

  def count
    @total_count
  end
end

class Parent
  has_many :kids do
    def chatty_with_singleton
      resultset = where(:chatty => true)
      def resultset.count
        proxy_association.owner.chatty_kids_count
      end
      resultset
    end

    def chatty_with_delegation
      resultset = where(:chatty => true)
      CountDelegator.new(resultset, proxy_association.owner.chatty_kids_count)
    end
  end
end

p = Parent.first
```

Now, when I do either `p.kids.chatty_with_singleton.count` or `p.kids.chatty_with_delegation.count`, I use the cached count. Great! However, the following behave differently:

```
# Uses the cached count
p.kids.chatty_with_singleton(:order => "id desc").count

# Does not use the cached count
p.kids.chatty_with_delegation(:order => "id desc").count
```

I'm totally confused — I don't know why these two cases would behave differently in practice. (Yes, I'm aware that `p.kids.chatty_with_singleton(:id => 0).count` returns the wrong value and I am okay with that.)

Why does defining the method on the singleton resultset cause that definition to dominate, while the delegator doesn't?

Comment: Or you could just use `.size` which does exactly that...

Comment: http://work.stevegrossi.com/2015/04/25/how-to-count-with-activerecord/

Comment: This is not a `size()` vs `count()` issue. When I delegate both `size()` and `count()`, `p.chatty_kids_with_delegation.order("id desc").size` runs the COUNT query rather than using my cached attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-implementing the built-in [`counter_cache`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) option provided by `belongs_to`. You simply specify the column of your cache as well, if you're not using the rails default column.

Using the `counter_cache` will automatically read the cached value on table instead of executing a `COUNT`.

Comment: I don't think I'm quite using a counter cache. For one thing, it doesn't look like counter_cache will let me only count in some cases (eg, kids where chatty = true) and for another, I'm keeping my counter up to date with database triggers (I occasionally update the table outside Rails) and don't want Rails to try and bump the column value. But maybe I can look at how counter caches are implemented and try to steal that.